sudo apt get update reply ign and temporary failure resolving
when I write the command sudo apt-get update, it replies to a range of ign and temporary failed. Also my network manager not running. Those errors start when I uninstall the pi-hole. It asks me do I wish to remove git and iptables. I thought it was the pi-hole file so I said yes.

Reasons could be many, including you're using a release that is now EOL & thus mirrors have dropped support & the main archive has moved.  Without know what Ubuntu product/release you're using we can only guess.  For us to provide specific advice, we need specific details as to what you're running (and be specific with your pastes, ie. post both command & output of command if you wish our help with it, otherwise we can only be generic in responses)

This question is similar to: What does 'Ign', 'Get' or 'Hit' mean when running an apt-get update?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
