sudo apt get update ign and temporary and
When I write the command sudo apt get update, it replies a range of ign and temporary failed.
Also, my network manager is not running.
Those errors started when I uninstalled pi-hole; it asked me do you wish to remove git and iptables 2. I thought it was the pi hole file, so I say yes.
And now when I try to install ipstables, it says package iproute2 has no installation candidate.
Please have me. I have fixed it for 6 hours but it does not work.
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/jammy main InRelease               
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 https://deb.obsproject.com/obs-studio jammy InRelease                    
Ign:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/jammy main InRelease               
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 https://deb.obsproject.com/obs-studio jammy InRelease                    
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/jammy main InRelease                    
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease            
  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpadcontent.net'
Err:1 https://deb.obsproject.com/obs-studio jammy InRelease             
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.obsproject.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/jammy main InRelease                    
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/jammy/dists/main/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpadcontent.net'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.obsproject.com/obs-studio/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.obsproject.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.```


This question is similar to: Ubuntu Server 18.04 Temporary failure in name resolution. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You've asked this question before - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521588/sudo-apt-get-update-reply-ign-and-temporary-failure-resolving    Either delete the prior question; or edit it and add the details there.  SE rules don't allow the same question to be asked twice.

This question is similar to: apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's internet connection fault, check connection by ping
$ ping -c 4 1.1.1.1
And if work perfectly try again

it said network is unreaable

Are you even connected to internet? If yes, check nameservers at /etc/resolv.conf
